# Rails app 502 with AWS Elastic Beanstalk running Puma & Nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, elastic-beanstalk

I've been able to successfully get my application running on Beanstalk with Passenger, however I've had no luck with Puma.  Whenever I deploy with to a Puma stack I get 502 Errors, my log files indicate that it can't find the sock file:

`2014/05/15 21:00:15 [crit] 1684#0: *4 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.184.156.117, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "app-env-89spnxpcai.elasticbeanstalk.com"`

My app is built using Ruby ruby 2.0.0p451 & Rails 4.1.1

My .ebextensions config looks like this

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []

commands:
  add_bundle_exec:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
    command: perl -pi -e 's/(rake)/bundle exec $1/' 11_asset_compilation.sh 12_db_migration.sh
  add_deployment_flag:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
    command: perl -pi -e 's/(bundle install)/$1 --deployment/' 10_bundle_install.sh
  make_vendor_bundle_dir:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    command: mkdir /var/app/support/vendor_bundle
  set_vendor_bundle_var:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
    command: sed -i '12iexport EB_CONFIG_APP_VENDOR_BUNDLE=$EB_CONFIG_APP_SUPPORT/vendor_bundle' envvars
  symlink_vendor_bundle:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/.post-provisioning-complete
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre
    command: sed -i 's/\(^cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK\)/\1\nln -s $EB_CONFIG_APP_VENDOR_BUNDLE .\/vendor\/bundle/' 10_bundle_install.sh
  z_write_post_provisioning_complete_file:
    cwd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
    command: touch .post-provisioning-complete
```

What am I doing wrong, do I need something special to get it to work with Puma?

Comment: I found this answer. I'm sure you've found a solution but for the other searchers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355569/rails-application-deployed-on-elastic-beanstalk-with-puma-fails-502-errors-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue does not present itself with the newest version - 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.5 running Ruby 2.0 (Puma)

Comment: I have same config but still getting `502`. It shows `connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client` error

Comment: @AmitPatel which AMI are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `config.force_ssl = true` to `false` fixed the issue for me